# (Reversing)(LLDB) How can I pass stdin to binary in remote-ios debugging?

Tags: remote-debugging, lldb, reversing

same as title.

It's so simple binary.
gets and print

lldb in local iDevice is fine.
[debbugging in local iDevice directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caD6s.png)

but in remote-ios platform, I dont' know how to pass stdin to binary.
[debugging in remote lldb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SB1o.png)

1. iDevice : debugserver 127.0.0.1:1234 /qwerty
2. Mac.

   1. lldb
   2. platform select remote-ios
   3. process connect connect://127.0.0.1:1234

Thanks to all the answers.